# jQuery Alert when class is found

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a section of code that applies a class when the page is scrolled down (Sticky Header and I am not sure where the main script is/what plugin).

Is there a way that when this class lets say `"test"` is found that it shows an alert?

Comment: use `.hasCLass()` https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Comment: Please show us the code/HTML you have so far so we know more precisely what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  `hasClass()`

The `hasClass()` method checks if any of the selected elements have a specified class name.

**Syntax**

```
$(selector).hasClass(classname)
```